# How to say "I met someone", but not in the romantic way

Tags: phrase-requests, expression-choice

I sometimes start stories with "I met someone who (...)" or "I met a man who (...)".

Being a woman, people often seem to think there is something romantic about the meeting even though that was not my original intention.

Is there another turn of phrase that can be used that has fewer romantic connotations? I find "I met a person (...)" to be rather awkward.

Comment: You could say (if this was some time in the past) "I once met a man ..."  The "once" implies that there was not a long-lasting relationship, at least.  Also, saying "I ran into..." rather than "I met ..." implies a more casual relationship (though it confuses a bit because it implies that you might have known the person previously).

Comment: _encountered_ is a highbrow word that could be used.

Comment: Yeah; I feel that 'ran into' implies familiarity. I would probably use 'encountered'.

Comment: Colloquially, _bumped into_ is unmarked for romance (but also has the literal meaning, and again connotes a previous relationship). 'Came across' may work.

Comment: Unless there is enough context to clarify the situation, 'encountered' as an alternative is compromised by the existence of the collocation 'sexual encounter'.

Comment: While "I [just] met a man" or "I [just] met someone" (or perhaps even any of the good suggestions so far) all alone would certainly imply a romantic spark, I think when followed by "who" the words following the "who" would adequately suffice to either confirm or refute the romantic implication, no? "Guy" is certainly a good choice for the reasons given in the answer, as would perhaps be "THIS man who" or "THIS guy who," but, again, without the "who," the romantic implication will still be there, IMO. Maybe "I [just] met a nasty man" would not imply a romantic spark, but even then, who knows?

Comment: If you know their job title or profession: *I met an accountant on the train today. He was looking to hire (...)*

Comment: Phrases like "I remember meeting someone..." could also fit here as you are implying stories here.

Comment: @Moderators: Would this question be better suited to the "English Language Learners" site, then? English IS my second language, admittedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *Let me tell you about some man that I ran into while I was [shopping].*

1. Leading with, ***Let me tell you about***, makes this about you, your friend, and the story you are about to tell. The man is an *incidental* feature of the story-telling experience.
2. ***Some man*** communicates an *anonymity* that further suppress any romantic inference. If you are speaking the story, rather than writing it, your intonation could evoke various levels of distant curiosity, disregard, or even contempt in the minds of your listeners.
3. The relative pronoun ***that*** serves to subtly *depersonalize* this anonymous incidental character.
4. ***I ran into*** implies an extraneous *fleeting* confrontation that interrupted your actual agenda.
5. Finishing your introduction with [***the active context***] of this encounter tends to emphasize the activity over the character, effectively *burying* this man in the other details of the story you are about to tell.
6. I considered recommending a **synonym** for *man*, but they all risk drawing undue attention to him. A synonym could even backfire, depending on the context between you and the person you are telling the story to. If you have a synonym that would *certainly* burry this fleeting extraneous character more deeply into the impersonal background of your story, feel free.
7. **Beware**: if you are telling this story to another woman, she may inuit your devices, assume you are trying to hide your mad passionate attraction to him, and feed your platonic heart to the romantic dogs.

Comment: This is my favourite answer, specifically option #3 "that/this guy" because it doesn't depend on other factors such as divulging more details about the person in question, the timespan between the encounter and the telling of the story, or the current or previous status of the relationship with the person.

Also, #7 tends to happen a lot, which is the reason for this question in the first place! :)

Comment: Their obsession with the romantic milieu of your stories, is their problem not yours. Enjoy your stories and let their obsession be water off a ducks back! Now that I am married, my friends don't do it, but back in the day, when they did that to me, I executed a *romantic jujitsu* move on them by offering to look the gal up, and introduce her to them, so they could pursue ***their*** romantic fantasies with her.

Answer (score 3):

If the person you met was male, you might try "I met a guy who..." or "I ran across a guy who..." These are not as close  to romantically-linked phrases like "looking for a man", and might serve your purposes.

Comment: Even less likely to be taken romantically is “I met this guy who…”.

Comment: "I met a guy" is about as likely to be mistaken for a romantic encounter as "I met a man". In fact, I'd say it's more likely - the sentence "I met a guy." all by itself implies romance, while "I met a man." by itself does not.

Answer (score 3):

Here are some suggestions:

> - I once was acquainted with a man who . . .
> - Looking back on my life, I recall a man I once met who . . .
> - I remember meeting a man years ago who . . .
> - I recall meeting a man who . . .
> - I seem to recall--though the details are fuzzy--meeting a man once who . . .
> - A man I met once, briefly, back in my teen years . . .
> - A man I was acquainted with when I was in my late twenties . . .
> - I was introduced to a gentleman many years ago now who . . .
> - While on vacation in Barbados, I met a man who . . .
> - I made the acquaintance of a man in 2006 who . . .
> - I once spent some time in the presence of a man while traveling . . .
> - I once met an unforgettable character, a man, who introduced himself to me as . . .
> - [I met a man the other day](http://lyrics.wikia.com/Rolf_Harris:Big_Black_Hat), he was dressed in a very strange way
>
>   With a great big hat with a big black brim (With a great big hat with a big black 
>     brim)
>
>   And that's not all! (And that's not all!)
>
>   'Cause around his leg was a big black chain and
>
>   Dragging on the chain was a big black ball

Well, I think you get the idea.